# Session timed out after 60 seconds

Tags: c#, selenium, iis, selenium-chromedriver

In my ASP.net MVC application, I'm using selenium c# chrome driver for some automation purpose. My application works fine when I run the application through VS. But after hosting application in IIS server following error occurred.

> The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL
>   http://localhost:35756/session timed out after 60 seconds

and some times this error too

> Message :The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL
>   http://localhost:14003/session/39f4131f839af646da1b9855ce8d091b/element/0.6598483585083559-1/click
>   timed out after 60 seconds.

```
Message :The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:35756/session timed out after 60 seconds.
StackTrace :   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(String chromeDriverDirectory, ChromeOptions options)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(String chromeDriverDirectory)
```

Previously this worked for me.but since few days I'm getting this error. Do anyone have an idea to solve this problem?

Part of my code:

```
try{

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddArguments("--proxy-server=http://192.168.5.62:8095");
    options.AddUserProfilePreference("safebrowsing.enabled", true);
    options.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true");
    options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", downPath);

    using (var driver = new ChromeDriver(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath,options))
    {
        // Go to the home page
        //driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);             
    }   
}
catch (Exception ex)
{      
    log.Error(ex);
    Logger.LogWriter("SITS", ex, "CRIBLogic", "Download");
}
```

I read several threads regarding this problem. But I'm not found a proper answer

- [The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL - Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50720132/the-http-request-to-the-remote-webdriver-server-for-url-chrome)
- https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5457
- https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4942

Comment: You are unable to use session on shared hosting as it will impact to other client sites on that server. As an alternative, please use cookies or session state.